# PDF or Excel the file created is always blank with 0 byte in sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to develop report in sharepoint foundation 2010.

The report is developed in rdlc format.

I am able to display the result in the report viewer control. But when I export it to PDF or Excel, the file created is always blank with 0 byte.

Anyone face this problem before?

I had tried reinstall the Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package. but the issue still exists.